# Photogrametry using e-Foto (Stereo Plotter, Stereo Imagery, Stereoscopy)

Tags: photogrammetry, stereo-imagery

I'm learning Photogrametry with Stereo-view using e-Foto (http://www.efoto.eng.uerj.br/en). At the end, **I want to know how to do Photogrametry via Stereoscopy in PC with Anaglyph Glasses**.

I could replicate successfully e-Foto's tutorial, however trying to work with my own data like Imagery taken by an UAV, Digital Camera, UTM Ground Control Points, Camera Calibration with AgiSoft Lens, I couldn't get a good Stereo-View to work with.

## 1. My opinion.

**I think this is happening because the camera calibration parameters.**

[image: e-Foto Camera parameters form]
[image: AgiSoft Lens Camera calibration]

Do the parameters need to be converted?

**I also think that is because the orientation-rotation. I dont know what this is.**
[image: e-Foto Fixed parameter]

**And finally the Fiducial Marks**
[image: e-Foto Fiducial marks]

My imagery doesn't have fiducial marks, so for this I made manually the marks in the images.

2. What other software do you recomend for stereo-imagery or stereo-view? (I hope use an Anaglyph 3D Glasses)

Answer (score 0):

Since I started working in this kind of project, I found some interesting software that might help me in Stereo Analysis, but, by my own experience. I found as the best solution ERDAS IMAGINE.