# Stereoscopy Software

Tags: software-recommendations, imagery, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, stereo-imagery

I'm learning the Manual Photogrammetry process, **Stereoscopy**, to Process **UAV Imagery**.
I'd like to know about others software, especially open source or low cost.

- ERDAS Imagine, Erdas Extensions for ArcGIS.
- Menci StereoTools.
- Digi3d.
- E-foto (I tried this but without success, If you like to help me [Photogrametry using e-Foto (Stereo Plotter, Stereo Imagery, Stereoscopy)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119649/photogrametry-using-e-foto-stereo-plotter-stereo-imagery-stereoscopy))
- EnsoMOSAIC.

Comment: OpenMVG (open Multiple View Geometry)  http://imagine.enpc.fr/~moulonp/openMVG/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think [SFM Toolkit](http://www.visual-experiments.com/demos/sfmtoolkit/) (FOSS)is used for this task. Although I have not used it, it is very well reviewed.

I have used [Stereo GIS](http://simwright.com/stereogis.htm) by SimWright and had good success. They may give you a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

I would check OSSIM http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/ and perhaps also this years Google Summer of Code project may interest you
http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki/GsocDSMGenerationToolForOSSIM